# LINQ to Microsoft SQL 2000 in C# using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2000, datacontext

Is it possible to create a DataContext for connection to a Microsoft SQL Server 2000 using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: In terms of mainstream support, SQL Server 2000 has been dead for 4 years. In extended support, it has 6-odd months to go. I *really* must advise you to consider an upgrade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hope this Information helps:

> Mainstream support for SQL Server 2000 ended on 04/08/2008. Visual
>   Studio 2010 only supports SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008/2008 R2.
>   In order to continue working with SQL Server 2000, you may use any of
>   the earlier releases of Visual Studio.
>
> The ODBC connection is still enabled as ODBC is version independent.
>   You will find many features disabled for ODBC connections.

[see source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/37d137be-f119-4d49-bddf-99f398328096/)

---

[Microsoft states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) that some functionalities like Take and Skip have certain limitations when they are used in queries against SQL Server 2000, which means it works but with limitations.

Check [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1295232.aspx/1) too.